# how to copy frame from tab to new tab in tabwidget pyqt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer

How to copy tab1 frame to new tab which is dynamically added using QPushButton and addTab function.

Trying to create gui with "Insert Tab" button that will add new tab with predefined frame and settings,
but its replacing frame from tab1 to new tab if I go back to tab one its missing the frame which i used in new tab.
How can I copy the widgets instead of moving it while adding new tab?

ui file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1120</width>
    <height>850</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>1121</width>
     <height>721</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(253, 255, 242);</string>
   </property>
   <property name="currentIndex">
    <number>0</number>
   </property>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
    <attribute name="title">
     <string>Tab 1</string>
    </attribute>
    <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>0</x>
       <y>0</y>
       <width>1111</width>
       <height>691</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="styleSheet">
      <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(255, 243, 242);</string>
     </property>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_frame">
      <property name="geometry">
       <rect>
        <x>700</x>
        <y>210</y>
        <width>171</width>
        <height>80</height>
       </rect>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>30</x>
         <y>30</y>
         <width>47</width>
         <height>13</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Hello saqib</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </widget>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
    <attribute name="title">
     <string>Tab 2</string>
    </attribute>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="change">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>60</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>93</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Change Text</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="insert">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>220</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>93</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Insert Tab</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="remove">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>390</x>
     <y>50</y>
     <width>93</width>
     <height>28</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Remove Tab</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

python main:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PySide2.QtCore import *


class MainWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("tabtutorial.ui", self)
        self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.tabChanged)
        self.change.clicked.connect(self.changeTabText)
        self.insert.clicked.connect(self.insertTab)
        self.remove.clicked.connect(self.removeTab)

    def tabChanged(self):
        print("Tab was changed to ", self.tabWidget.currentIndex())

    def changeTabText(self):
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(0, "First tab")
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(1, "Second tab")

    def insertTab(self):
        self.label.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Dialog", "Hello test", None))
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.widget, "New Tab")

    def removeTab(self):
        self.tabWidget.removeTab(0)


# main
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = MainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedHeight(850)
widget.setFixedWidth(1120)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Output:

this Tab1 have a frame with "Hello Saq" label under frame widget.
[image]

If I insert new tab (using the above code addTab(self.widget, "New Tab") function its adding the frame to new tab but now its missing in the Tab1

[image]

[image]

Is there any way to copy widget instead of moving it?

Comment: There is no way to automatically "copy" complex objects, you have to manually recreate the widget contents (children and layout), using instance constructors of the relative classes (QWidget, QLabel, etc). I'd suggest you to try to generate a python file using the pyuic tool and study its contents to understand how it works (but open them just for that reason, don't consider editing those files for production, as it's a bad practice).

Comment: I tried reading the documenation and the converted python file seems like i cant reuse the widget object, is there any tutorial or example you can help me with to achieve this? trying pyqt5 first time.
Just want to add a template layout at a certain position which will be reused every time i click add button.

Comment: You don't reuse the widget (widgets are like physical objects, they cannot be put in two places at the same time). *Study* the pyuic files and the documentation of the classes/functions they use to understand **how** widgets (and their children) are created. Qt is a wonderful but extremely extended toolkit, you cannot expect to get it in a few days: it might take weeks, months, or even years to master it. Take your time, be patient, **study the documentation**, and test yourself. Sorry but StackOverflow is not a tutorial or example website.